# Stuck on limits with exponent

Tags: limits

I'm trying to solve the limit below.

$$
\lim_{n\to \infty }(1/2)^{n^2-n}  
$$

I know the answer is 0, and it's quite obvious to me due to the different degree of $n^2$ and $n$.

AFAIK $\infty -\infty$ is forme indeterminate that imply i must change the limit content to something different without indeterminate, but I don't know how...

Comment: @Downvoter. Let me at least the pleasure of telling me how can my question be improved to meet your requirement. If the problem is my basic level or level of question.... f...nny

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: $(1/2)^{n^2-n}$ the exponent goes to what, it goes to $\infty$? What is $0.5^{\infty}=0.5\cdot 0.5 \cdots $? In order to show that $n^2$ is larger you can look at $n^2-n=n^2(1-1/n)$, which clearly goes to infinity.

Comment: Ok, so I just need to treat the exponential part as I do for the other exercise...it was obvious the idea, but I was not sure about how to mathematically show it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Try  $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{n^2-n} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \left(\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^n\right)^{n-1}$$

Alternatively, for positive integer $n \gt N$ you have $n^2-n \gt N^2$ so  $$\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{n^2-n} \lt \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{N^2}$$

Answer (score 1):

It is true that $\infty-\infty$ is an indeterminate form, but that doesn't mean that there is anything wrong about the limit $\lim_{n\to\infty} n^2-n$; ***only*** that *taking limits of $n^2$ and $n$ separately will not be helpful*.

In fact, you have a perfectly reliable intuition that $\lim_{n\to\infty} n^2-n$ is $+\infty$, as you say, because of the difference in degree. The fact that one particular strategy for evaluating the limit won't work (which, again, is *all* "indeterminate" tells you) doesn't change that.